# Looking for shortcut key for Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I opened a program via linux terminal, and after some search in Google I find out that I can close the program by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. If I want to run the program, but at the same time have a new line in the command terminal (like I have when I close the program) to do some other work.  Is there any shortcut key?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different possiblities:

#### If your program is already running

Press `CTRL+Z` to *suspend* your program. It will not be running now. To resume the program in the background, type `bg` and press ENTER.

#### If you want to start a new program in the background directly

Simply add `&` to your program before you start it:
`$ geany "do_while.cpp" &`

You might find that the program outputs status or error messages on your shell. These messages will not directly affect the commands you type, but can be very disturbing. You can suppress/discard this output by redirecting it to `/dev/null`:
`$ geany "do_while.cpp" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

---

For more information on job management in the Shell:

- [What is effect of CTRL + Z on a unix\Linux application](https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application)
- [Unix.SE - Ctrl-C vs Ctrl-Z with foreground job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/135077/ctrl-c-vs-ctrl-z-with-foreground-job)
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/